# &#160 shows up as a '?' question mark on HTML

Tags: html, jsp, xslt, character-encoding

i have a problem with XSLT...

```
<xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
```

Then after generation, for some reason the resulting JSP file produces a '?' instead. What's wrong?

My recent system changes:
I changed Java5 -> Java6
Weblogic -> Weblogic12
Eclipse Ganymede -> Oracle Pack Eclipse

EDIT 1:  `<xsl:output method="xml"/>`, encoding=UTF-8

The original XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:include href="common.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    ...

    <xsl:template name="makeLink">
        <xsl:variable name="fieldtype" select="name()"/>

        <xsl:variable name="currentNode"><xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/></xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="appendSpace">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ButtonList[position() = 1]/descendant::Button">
                <xsl:if test="generate-id() = $currentNode and position() &gt; 1">true</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

<a href="{$url}">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">btn_<xsl:value-of select="Action"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:call-template name="populateAttributes">
                <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$fieldtype"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>

            <xsl:copy-of select="@class"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@style"/>

            <xsl:text>&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$buffer"/><xsl:text>&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</xsl:text>
</a>
        <xsl:if test="not(@omitWhiteSpace)">
            <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="ReadOnly and ReadOnly != 'someReadOnlyMethod'
            and ReadOnly != 'someReadyOnlyMethod'
            and ReadOnly != ''">
            <xsl:text>&lt;/c:if&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
....
```

Transformed (after XSLT), and resulting JSP page:

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/html;charset=GBK"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored = "false"%>
<%@ page language="java" 
import=" my.controller.*, my.core.config.*, my.core.datastructure.*, my.core.error.*, my.core.util.*,
my.service.Constants, my.service.modulesvr.ModuleBean, myW.sn.*, java.util.Locale, java.util.Map"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.mycompany.com/my/tags/htmltag-10" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%MySn mySession = (MySn) session.getValue("MySn"); QuickSearchController mb = (mySession == null) ? null : (QuickSearchController)
mySession.getModuleBean(); String sessionToken = mySession.getSessionToken(); String htmlCharSet = mySession.getEncoding();
MyUsr user = mySession.getMyUsr(); String[] result; Object o;%>

.........

<a href="#" id="btn_NEWPROP" onclick="submitForm('/xxx/xxx/NEWPROP','theForm');    return (false);" class="actionBtn"><span><span>NEW PROP</span></span></a> </c:if>
```

EDIT 2: it seems like if i use `<xsl:text>&amp;#160;</xsl:text>` instead of `<xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>`...the problem seems to have gone away. In the JSP, it will appear as &#160 and on the browser, it is seen as a no-break space, which is expected.

Comment: Seems unlikely, but have you checked it isn't your font failing to display an unsupported character? (as I say, it seems unlikely, given that #160 is a non-breaking space, but its the only thing I can think of)

Comment: This is a classic encoding problem. What is your `<xsl:output>` declaration, how is the page put together and which HTTP headers does your server send?

Comment: the page is put together by generating XSL stylesheets through XSLT that produces a JSP page with JavaServerPages scriptlets and html elements.

Comment: @Tomalak, <xsl:output method="xml"/>, encoding=UTF-8

Comment: It is entirely impossible to guess where your error is as long as you don't share the relevant code. For example, does it say `<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />` or does the `encoding="UTF-8"` appear somewhere else in your XML/XSLT? Share a minimal (!) XML+XSLT sample that exposes the problem. How are the files processed? Share the relevant JSP/Java code. You did not say anything about the HTTP headers either. Analyze the HTTP response with a packet sniffer and find out what bytes go over the wire. There are so many places where something like this can go wrong, don't let us guess.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for the suggestions i have uploaded whatever code snippets i can because the XSLT process involves more than 12 files but i felt the above should be the most relevant bits...i will continue to dig deeper to find if more code is relevant or not. On the other hand, i dont even know where to look for the HTTP headers you mention :\

Comment: @Tomalak it seems like if i use <xsl:text>&amp;#160;</xsl:text> instead of <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>...the problem seems to have gone away. In the JSP, it will appear as &#160 and on the browser, it is seen as a no-break space, which is expected.

Comment: Your are doing several horrible things in your XSLT. For starters, one **never, ever** does `<xsl:text>&lt;span&gt;</xsl:text>`. NEVER. Why on earth are you doing this? If you want a `<span>`, write a `<span>` in your XSLT. Your XSLT is seriously broken and should be rewritten. For starters, try switching your entire processing chain to UTF-8. (`<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" />` and `<%@ page contentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>` and whereever else you are outputting data in a non-UTF8 encoding). There is no reason to use encodings like `GBK` anymore.

Comment: Seriously, I have no idea what you are doing here. I don't even see the part in your JSP that does the XSLT processing. Or is it done in another tool? I'm only guessing that you seem to be using XSLT to code-generate JSP files, but it looks all pretty messed up. I'm not sure if I can help you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That often happens if your encoding is wrong. What encoding are you writing your output in? How are you serving up the page? Possibly you are serializing in UTF-8 but trying to display in ISO-8859-1 (or Windows-1252), or vice-versa.

Check to see if the default encoding somewhere has changed.

Just because you say `<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>` doesn't mean that the program will honor it. Is the XSLT embedded in a piece of Java? Does the Java control the streams/readers/writers?

If you can save a portion of the file and dump it in HEX, you should quickly be able to find out. If you see `0xC2 0xA0` then your file is indeed in UTF-8. However, if you just see `0xA0` alone, then you are in ISO-8859-1 or one of its close relations.

It's also possible that the page is being rendered properly, but the page is being served up with the wrong encoding. Can you look at the headers returned, perhaps by using Firebug in Firefox or in Chrome "Web Developer->Information->View Response Headers" or by using the IE debug tools.

Comment: <xsl:output method="xml"/>, encoding=UTF-8

Comment: it seems like if i use <xsl:text>&amp;#160;</xsl:text> instead of <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>...the problem seems to have gone away. In the JSP, it will appear as &#160 and on the browser, it is seen as a no-break space, which is expected...i still dont know what went wrong..